# How to maintain the aspect ratio when using GPUImage cropFilter?

Tags: ios, swift, gpuimage, gpuimagestillcamera, android-gpuimageview

Now I am making a application to take square movies like Instagram.
I'm trying to use cropFilter in GPUImage to crop the video.
The video is really square but looks stretch and broken ratio.

I wrote like this.

```
videoView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.width, height: self.view.frame.width)
videoView.fillMode = kGPUImageFillModePreserveAspectRatioAndFill
self.view.addSubview(videoView)
videoCamera.outputImageOrientation = .Portrait
videoCamera.addTarget(videoView)

let documentDirectory = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)[0]

let fileName = "video.mp4"
pathToMovie = (documentDirectory as NSString).stringByAppendingPathComponent(fileName)
let movieURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: pathToMovie)
unlink((pathToMovie as NSString).UTF8String)

movieWriter = GPUImageMovieWriter(movieURL: movieURL, size: CGSize(width: 480, height: 480))
movieWriter.encodingLiveVideo = true
movieWriter.shouldPassthroughAudio = true
movieWriter.assetWriter.movieFragmentInterval = kCMTimeInvalid
videoCamera.addTarget(movieWriter)
videoCamera.audioEncodingTarget = movieWriter

let cropFilter = GPUImageCropFilter(cropRegion: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0.125, width: 1.0, height: 0.75))
videoCamera.addTarget(cropFilter)
cropFilter.addTarget(movieWriter)

videoCamera.startCameraCapture()
movieWriter.startRecording()
```

any one, please help.

Comment: did you try kGPUImageFillModePreserveAspectRatioAndFit in `fillMode`  ?

Comment: I resolved this problem by using videoCamera.setInputFramebufferForTarget() instead of videoCamera.addTarget. thanks!

Comment: thank you for sharing :)